# Turn list into "list of lists"

Tags: r, list

How can i transform the first "long" list l:

```
l <- list()
n=1
for (i in 1:9) {
  l[[length(l)+1]] <- n:(n+2)
  n=n+3
}
```

into a wider but shorter list of lists lol: In the next code segment im breaking after every 3 Elements of l.

```
lol <- list()
lol[[1]] <- list(1:3,4:6,7:9)
lol[[2]] <- list(10:12,13:15,16:18)
lol[[3]] <- list(19:21,22:24,25:27)
```

Any ideas? What if i want to break after every 2 Elements of l.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split it by a vector `1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3`:

```
n = 3                                     # the length of each sub list
split(l, (seq_along(l) - 1) %/% n)

identical(lol, setNames(split(l, (seq_along(l) - 1) %/% 3), NULL))
# [1] TRUE
```

Comment: This doesn't pass the `identical` check, but another way: `tapply(l, rep(1:3, each=3), FUN = c)`

Comment: @Psidom perfect solution!

Comment: @Frank i believe its because of the names of the list elements. Your solution is not general enough.For e.g if you split by 2 it doesnt work. Nice use of tapply anyways!